# Enable Azure AD Login in Azure APIM new developer portal

Tags: azure, azureportal

Any idea how to enable Azure Login in new developer portal? I have tried below link to set up account on azure AD. It enabled AD login in old developer portal but not in new one

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad

Any link which can help with this?

Comment: Is this functionlity available in new developer portal? can anyone please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has not been released on Azure APIM new developer portal yet. Details [see here](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/27) . 
As APIM product team indicated , this feature is comming soon :

> it will be completed by general availability release, which is planned
>   for October/November.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Stanley. I had been trying this since long. :)

Answer (score 0):

Now Its enabled. I was able to configure to azureAD sign in.
Note: To Auto populate Sign up page. need to add additional claim (email) in the Azure AD App.
can follow below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/145976/can-sign-up-page-be-auto-populated-after-aad-authe.html